# Parsing text file from JSON spec file, Bad data in Postman

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing, postman

Here is the controller class for my files. I am trying to parse a flat-file text file based upon a json specification. THe spec gives the names of fields along with the startIndex and length. Each text file has a different spec JSON file.

```
    package com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.controllers;

    import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.config.FixedLengthFileConfiguration;
    import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.entities.FileDataEntity;
    import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.respositories.FileDataRepository;
    import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.services.FileParserService;
    import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.services.MetadataService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileParserService fileParserService;

    @Autowired
    private FileDataRepository fileDataRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FixedLengthFileConfiguration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private MetadataService metadataService;

    @PostMapping("/metadata")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadMetadata(@RequestParam("specFile") MultipartFile specFile,
                                                 @RequestParam("pathName") String pathName) {
        try {
            String jsonSpecFile = new String(specFile.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            metadataService.parseAndSaveMetadata(jsonSpecFile, pathName);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Metadata uploaded successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading metadata.");
        }
    }

    private void saveParsedData(List<Map<String, String>> parsedData) {
        for (Map<String, String> record : parsedData) {
            FileDataEntity mapDataEntity = new FileDataEntity();
            mapDataEntity.setData(record);
            fileDataRepository.save(mapDataEntity);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/parse")
    public List<Map<String, String>> parseFixedLengthFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                                          @RequestParam("spec") MultipartFile specFile) throws IOException {
        List<Map<String, String>> parsedData = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                parsedData.add(parseLine(line, specFile.getInputStream()));
            }
        }
        saveParsedData(parsedData);
        return parsedData;

    }

    private Map<String, String> parseLine(String line, InputStream inputStream) {
        Map<String, FixedLengthFileConfiguration.FixedLengthField> fields = configuration.getFields();
        if (fields == null) {
            // Handle null fields map appropriately (e.g., throw an exception or log a message)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fields map is null");
        }

        Map<String, String> parsedData = new HashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, FixedLengthFileConfiguration.FixedLengthField> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = entry.getKey();
            FixedLengthFileConfiguration.FixedLengthField field = entry.getValue();
            int startIndex = field.getStart();
            int length = field.getLength();

            if (line.length() >= startIndex + length) {
                String fieldValue = line.substring(startIndex, startIndex + length).trim();
                parsedData.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the line does not contain enough characters for the field
                // You can choose to skip this field or handle it differently based on your requirements
                // For example, you can log a warning or set a default value for the field
            }
        }
        return parsedData;
    }

    // Implement other endpoints as needed
}
```

This is the JSON spec file along with the text file to parse:

```
{
  "fields": [
    { "name": "firstName", "startIndex": 0, "length": 10 },
    { "name": "lastName", "startIndex": 10, "length": 10 },
    { "name": "age", "startIndex": 17, "length": 20 }
  ]
}
```

```
John      Doe       25
Jane      Smith     30
Alice     Johnson   22
```

```
Here is the output from postman: 

[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Alice",
        "lastName": "Johnson"
    }
]
```

Why am I not getting the age field from the file. Is there an error in my parsing logic?

I tried parsing the file based upon the spec file above and am getting an incorrect result from postman.

Comment: I know nothing about postman, but I'd double check that the age field is 20 characters long. It looks like 2 in your sample.

Comment: Postman is only returning what's sent from the server. I wouldn't have thought this was a Postman specific issue - Do you get the same response with cURL or a different tool?